# Validating a query string in php

Tags: php

If I have a query string such as: `http://mywebsite.co.uk/charge.php?val=5768`

how can I validate this query string to throw an error with php if the user changes the value of the 'val' in the query string. Could I write some code on the charge.php page to do this?

Comment: Yes you could. I'm sure you can figure it out.

Comment: Please could you give me a hint maybe I'm new to php

Comment: Generally Rifki, StackOverflow is used to post code examples of what you have tried, what errors you are getting, and ask for help fixing those errors. Not for people to write the code for you.

Comment: What do you have in `charge.php`?

Comment: $val = $_GET['val'];
    echo "$val";

Comment: `if ($_GET['val'] != '5768') die();`

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you're barking up the wrong tree. You cannot detect if someone "changes" something. All you get is a request for a URL, and that's it. You typically have no idea where that request came from or who provided the URL; you need to evaluate the request on its own merits.

I'm guessing you have some confidential action that's taking place when someone visits that URL. And the value changes some important part of that action. Then you need to create server-side checks and bounds that confirm whether the user is currently allowed to do whatever he requests to do there. You need to have enough information stored on the server to be able to confirm whether the action the user is about to make is allowed or not. You cannot simply trust the information in the URL, because anyone can tamper with it.

How to do this specifically in your case is not clear, since I have no concrete idea what's supposed to be happening there.

Comment: I'm scared it has to do with the question 6 hours ago ([using Stripe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481482/stripe-gateway-log-doesnt-show-amount)). I would not be comfortable paying on a website that had to build code that was only secure because "I couldn't change the GET param".

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the val is an integer and if the val exists in the database. I use a function like following to check integer:

```
// CHECK IF VALID INTEGER
function valid_integer($str)
{
    if (strlen($str) == strlen(preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $str) + 0) AND $str > 0 AND $str < 9999999999999)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

so then I can check the val like following

```
if (valid_integer($_GET['val']))
{
    echo 'valid int';
}
    else
    {
        echo 'not valid int';
    }
```

Then you have to check if the val exist in the database. If you use a db.